# Py - Possible to Input Text into Web page and Extract Result Silently?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, automation

I am trying to build a simple project where I need to access a public website, input a single string of text, and get the output from the result of "submitting" the string of text.

I know this can be done with Selenium but I was wondering if it's possible to do this silently. The webpage does not have an API, it's just a database where you input a single text of string, query the result and display it.

Is this possible to do at all with Python?, again hopefully silently where when this runs it won't take over the monitor and can potentially and eventually be done on an arduino?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Resolution:

I was able to do this with Selenium using headless (previously: phantom) options.

Works like a charm, no UI being invaded. Querying what I need takes 2.5 seconds to get results.